# Website not showing up on Google after removal of blocking robots metatags

Tags: google, google-search-console, google-index

A friend asked me to take a look at their website, which had been online for several months, but did not show up on Google. I noticed that they had a subdomain which did show up, so the query

```
site:hisdomain.com
```

showed some results, but all of them were from the subdomain. The query

```
site:hisdomain.com -SubdomainTitle
```

resulted in zero results, since it blocked all results from the subdomain, and there were no results from their main domain. The following query yielded zero results, too:

```
site:www.hisdomain.com
```

Then I noticed that they had some SEO Wordpress plugin active which was configured to generate `noindex, nofollow` meta tags on their pages. I removed this and the meta tag was gone. I logged in to **Google Webmasters**, submitted some **Fetch as Google** queries and told Google to **Submit to Index** them (on both `domain.com` as well as `www.domain.com`). I told my friend his site would appear on Google the next few days or weeks.

**This was several weeks ago, and his site still doesn't appear.**

Then I checked their **Index Status** on both `domain.com` and `www.domain.com`. Here's how it looks for `www.domain.com`:

[image]

[image]

It's strange that the `Blocked by robots` count has always been `0`. If the `robots` metatag was the reason for Google not indexing their site, there would have been some `Blocked by robots` results, I suppose.

**So, there must be another reason why Google doesn't index their site. Any ideas? How can I analyze the situation further?**

**EDIT:** Here's the URL: http://www.lab25.ch. The subdomain is not directly related to the main URL: http://addon-katakunst.lab25.ch. And no, **it's not duplicate content**.

Comment: Please share URL.

Comment: fetch has no outcome on indexing.... Can you explain the use of the sub domain, is it the same site? it'll help a lot if your just tell us the URL. Furthermore, if this is duplicate content being read on one domain and then you want it to be seen on another, it takes 3-8 weeks generally.

Comment: URL --> see edits

Comment: `fetch has no outcome on indexing` .. yes, but some people on this site recommend the use of the **Submit to Index** feature, see for example http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/23296/27500